# How to print excerpt and content in the head?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a simple plugin that prints the content and the excerpt in the head section. Below is the code I tried but didn't worked:

```
function content_excerpt() {
  if( is_single() ) {
  the_content();
  the_excerpt();
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'content_excerpt' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:-

```
  function content_excerpt() {
  if( is_single() ) {
//use global $post variable
  global $post;
    echo $post->post_content; //echoing post_content
    echo $post->post_excerpt; //echoing post_excerpt
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'content_excerpt' );
```

Comment: can you please print_r($post);